# Compile Error : expecting a colon

Tags: apex, soql

```
public static map<id,Account_Contact_Roles__c> getPrimaryContact(set<id> setSeedmanAccount)
{
    map<id,Account_Contact_Roles__c> mapdAccountContactRole = new map<id,Account_Contact_Roles__c>();
    if(setSeedmanAccount != null && setSeedmanAccount.size() > 0)
    {
        for(Account_Contact_Roles__c objAccConRole : [Select id, Account_SFID__r.id ,Contact_SFID__r.MobilePhone,Contact_SFID__r.Phone 
                                                        from Account_Contact_Roles__c 
                                                       where Account_SFID__c IN setSeedmanAccount AND Role_Descr__c = 'Primary Contact'])
        {
            mapdAccountContactRole.put(Account_SFID__r.id, objAccConRole);
        }

    }
    return mapdAccountContactRole;

}
```

i keep getting error `"Error: Compile Error: expecting a colon, found 'setSeedmanAccount' at line 3,732 column 84"`

in our case the error is at line "where Account_SFID__c IN setSeedmanAccount AND Role_Descr__c = 'Primary Contact'])"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While using a variable in a SOQL query you should add a `:` before it:

```
where Account_SFID__c IN :setSeedmanAccount
```

You can read more here: [Using Apex Variables in SOQL and SOSL Queries](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_variables.htm)

Comment: i got the error .thanks a lot

as well as line will be like this
 mapdAccountContactRole.put(objAccConRole.Account_SFID__r.id, objAccConRole);

Answer (score 0):

When you want to use an apex variable in a SOQL query you should put a colon(`:`) in front, so your query:

```
for(Account_Contact_Roles__c objAccConRole : [Select id, Account_SFID__r.id ,Contact_SFID__r.MobilePhone,Contact_SFID__r.Phone 
                                              from Account_Contact_Roles__c 
                                              where Account_SFID__c IN setSeedmanAccount AND Role_Descr__c = 'Primary Contact'])
```

would become:

```
for(Account_Contact_Roles__c objAccConRole : [Select id, Account_SFID__r.id ,Contact_SFID__r.MobilePhone,Contact_SFID__r.Phone 
                                              from Account_Contact_Roles__c 
                                              where Account_SFID__c IN :setSeedmanAccount AND Role_Descr__c = 'Primary Contact'])
```